# godaddy SSL with Ubuntu servers running Apache

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl

i have a godaddy ssl Standard certificate, and i have Ubuntu servers running Apache
i follow this page: http://www.codingepiphany.com/2014/11/26/installing-godaddy-ssl-certificate-in-an-ubuntu-server/
and i got apache error:

`[Wed Oct 05 03:42:08.986881 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1060] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Oct 05 03:42:10.011970 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 6821] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 05 03:42:10.013567 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 6821] AH02561: Failed to configure certificate dott.com:443:0, check /etc/ssl/gdssl/dott_com.crt
[Wed Oct 05 03:42:10.013618 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 6821] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06CSmiley TongueEM routinesSmiley TongueEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: CERTIFICATE) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Wed Oct 05 03:42:10.013661 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 6821] SSL Library Error: error:140AD009Smiley FrustratedSL routinesSmiley FrustratedSL_CTX_use_certificate_fileSmiley TongueEM lib
AH00016: Configuration Failed`

also when i load certificate
`openssl x509 -noout -text -in dott_com.crt -modulus | grep Modulus`
i got `unable to load certificate`

also server name is `dott.com` in godaddy and in config file too

Answer (score 0):

you might want to upload the certificate so someone can check it is actually valid. it may be corrupted or you incorrectly generated it(seems like the name form what the logs and erros are saying).

**be sure to keep the private key to yourself!**